# What is the relation of Aarti with different spiritual bodies?

Tags: rituals, practice

This is a extension of this [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/552/why-is-aarti-performed-to-deities-in-temples).

We have seen not only *Devi/Devtas* but also humans, plants and animals are welcomed through a spiritual deed called **'*Aarti*'**. Why it started? And what is its relations and resultants with different type of forms like *Humans*, *Plants* and *Animals*.

That question resolves round the deities, but we have experienced artis before animals and plants.

In addition to this the most common word used in Aarti is ***Aarti Utarna***,  why the term ***Utarna*** (pull down) used in the phrase? Is the word symbolic, or have any spiritual relationship?

The question does tries to describe the 'Arti', put fails to define why its pulled down (Utarna)?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, that question is limite to deties, mine is of broader view, similary I want to know why the Utarna word is attached to it.

Comment: I don't see how utarna word will change the question.

Comment: @Mr.K You might want to alter the question so that the primary focus is on that specific word. Right now that seems like a side note.