# Which type of ritual is aarati?

Tags: rituals, tradition

An important and famous part of pooja is aarati or nIrAjanam where ghee lamp or camphor light is used at the end of the pooja.

Does it come under puranic ritual or vedic too?

And what is the significance of deepArAdhana and deepadAna ?

Comment: http://www.indianscriptures.com/vedic-lifestyle/reasoning-customs/why-do-we-perform-aarti

Comment: @ArkaprabhaMajumdar there should be proper references about it

Comment: Nirajana is one the upacharas.

Comment: @Rickross yes that is known but its more of puranic worship or not

Comment: Yes Puranic and also Agamic. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: @RakeshJoshi yes that's why I added it in a comment.